# New SSL Certificate Breaks PHP cURL Requests

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, lamp

I just renewed a SSL certificate on a ubuntu lamp server and PHP cURL has broken. The server that has a new SSL certificate receives cURL posts from many other websites.

It looks like the server is still accepting some cURL requests from domains with SSL certificates. It is not accepting the majority of posts which are from Cloudflare hosted SSL certificates.

Is there another step that I have to do to the server to make it accept cURL posts from any domain?

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing reproducible in your question in general cURL vs. other clients is nothing special. Likely you did not install the new certificate properly which causes things to break. A common problem is that only the leaf certificate was configured but not the necessary intermediate certificates. Browsers often work around such misconfiguration cURL. But cURL will break since it cannot properly verify the certificate any longer, at least as long certificate validation is not disabled.

But again, these is pure speculation due to a lack of any information necessary to reproduce the problem in your question.